# Nextjs & Jest transform/transformIgnorePatterns not working with esm modules

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I've done a good amount of research on this and have found a decent amount of solutions. I have found what feels like a workaround and would like to get the `transform` and `transformIgnorePatterns` working. It seems the only thing I can get working however is to manually add some mock modules inside of my `__mocks__` folder.

Not sure if this is due to using `Nextjs` with `Jest` or not?

Here is my `jest.config.js`

```js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const esModules = ["react-markdown", "rehype-raw", "remark-gfm"].join("|");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",

    "^@/pages/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/pages/$1",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  transform: {
    [`(${esModules}).+\\.js$`]: "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!${esModules}).+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$`,
  ],
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

I have read that I will need a `babel.config.js` as well. Here is that file:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["next/babel", "@babel/preset-env"],
};
```

Comment: I'm stuck at the exact same place. Did you ever get this worked out?

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution in case someone runs into this same issue but is using `NextJs 12.2`, `next/jest` and `Jest 28`.

[Jest provides some experimental support for ECMAScript Modules (ESM)](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) but ["node_modules" are not transpiled by next/jest yet](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36077#issuecomment-1096698456).

So we need to use `transformIgnorePatterns` to prevent the ESM files from being transformed.

The default configuration for changing `transformIgnorePatterns` is [overwritten by `next/jest`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36077#issuecomment-1096635363) see below the solution for this.

```js
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Path to Next.js app to load next.config.js
  dir: './'
})

/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
const customJestConfig = {
  /**
   * Custom config goes here, I am not adding it to keep this example simple.
   * See next/jest examples for more information.
   */
 }

module.exports = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)()),
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    // The regex below is just a guess, you might tweak it
    'node_modules/(?!(react-markdown|rehype-raw|remark-gfm)/)',
  ]
})
```

I created a repository for a full reference of the necessary setup for a case that was using `swiper/react`.
https://github.com/markcnunes/with-jest-and-esm

Have in mind this setup might have to change for future `Next.js` / `next/js` versions but just sharing this approach in case this is useful for other people using this same setup.

I also used this answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926658/7883067) in case you are looking for solutions related to `swiper/react`.

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked for me with Jest v29 as long as I did also not set the `--experimental-vm-modules` flag when executing `jest`

Comment: How would you format the regexp for @firebase/auth module?

Comment: I am sorry Luis, I am not able to help you because I don't use `@firebase/auth`, you might want to create a new question for this.

Comment: This is amazing—I've spent hours trying to track this down! I can confirm this config also works with Next.js 13 and works well for transpiling `@aws-sdk` and its internal modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem specifically with `jest` and `react-dnd` as reported [here](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/3443).

I used the same solution as @Mark Nunes above, but tidied up a bit:

```js
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

const customJestConfig = {
  // You can add other jest config overrides here

  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],

  // DON'T SET THIS HERE - it's overridden below
  transformIgnorePatterns: [],
}

module.exports = async function() {
  const makeConfig = await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
  const finalJestConfig = await makeConfig()

  // This replaces the default of '/node_modules/'
  finalJestConfig.transformIgnorePatterns[0] =
    '/node_modules/(?!@react-dnd|react-dnd|dnd-core|react-dnd-html5-backend/)'

  return finalJestConfig
}
```