# Jest encountered an unexpected token with Next.js and TypeScript when using createUserWithEmailAndPassword in firebase/auth

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, jestjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up firebase authentication on [my Next.js project](https://github.com/Atticus29/video-annotator/tree/create-account) (using TypeScript), and I believe that I have encountered some configuration issues related to using firebase that are causing my Jest tests to fail.

Here are the relevant config files:

jest.config.js :

```
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",
    "^@/pages/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/pages/$1",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "firebase.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "video-annotator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.3",
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^6.2.5",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.3.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-formatjs": "^4.3.9",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "next-router-mock": "^0.9.1-beta.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5"
  }
}
```

And, in some of my attempted solutions below, you may also need to see:

tsconfig.jest.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

I have noticed that my test suite started failing when I added

```
const userInfo = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          email,
          password
        );
```

to the codebase in [pages/create-account/index.tsx](https://github.com/Atticus29/video-annotator/blob/create-account/pages/create-account/index.tsx) around ln. 94.

The displayed error is very strange. The test suite fails because, "Jest encountered an unexpected token".

Additionally, in the details section of the test output, I see:

Details:

```
.../video-annotator/node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/esm/index.esm.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from '@firebase/auth';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  10 | import { Paper } from "@mui/material";
  11 | import { Button } from "@mui/material";
> 12 | import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/authContext";
     |               ^
  13 | import { useContext } from "react";
```

[image: The error as displayed in my terminal]

I am confident that there is nothing wrong with the `import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/authContext";` statement, because if I swap that line of code with the one above it, I see this instead:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

```
  10 | import { Paper } from "@mui/material";
  11 | import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/authContext";
> 12 | import { Button } from "@mui/material";
     |               ^
```

Given my confidence that neither Button nor my AuthContext are the problem and noting that there are no errors in the tests until I comment back in the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` call:

```
const userInfo = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          email,
          password
        );,
```

, I have to conclude that either

1. I have misused the above statement somehow,
2. that something else is happening with the firebase import, or
3. that I have misconfigured jest somehow in a way that it's not playing well with firebase.

I explored the "Jest encountered an unexpected token" part of the error as well:

1. I tried adding "^firebase/auth$":
   "/node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/esm/index.esm.js", to jest.config.js in the moduleNameMapper and re-running the tests. No change.
2. I used ts-jest and [the Rust compiler](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#quickstart-2) instead of Babel during setup, so I figured that the provided link to https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript did not apply to my case.

I did, however try to replace my original jest.config.js from what is seen above to:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

This gave me a new variant of the "Jest encountered an unexpected token" error:

Details:

```
/Users/mf/Desktop/video-annotator/__tests__/login.test.tsx:39
    return (0, react_1.render)(<react_intl_1.IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1449:14).
```

This error in turn was similar to an issue reported [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8663), where they recommended splitting the config files into parts in order to prevent an automatic change from "react" to "preserve" :

> This issue is caused because jsx is not being transformed and jest
> doesn't know how to parse it. The fix is very simple, in your
> tsconfig.json you need to set the "jsx" key to "react" rather than
> "preserve". Unfortunately next's build expects it to be "preserve" and
> automatically changes it back in tsconfig.json :( The way I got around
> this was to create a seperate tsconfig.jest.json. Here are the steps:
>
> create a file tsconfig.jest.json with the following contents:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

> ... 2) configure jest.config.js to use the new tsconfig.jest.json.

I tried this as well, and it did not solve my issue.

I tried a few other suggestions in related SO posts as well, but none of them seemed to help in my particular case.

**I'm mostly looking for guidance on what to try next, unless solutions or mistakes immediately jump out a someone.** I think that I've made quite a mess of it all trying all of these different solutions.

Should I just switch to using Babel? It seems like there's a bigger community and history with Babel than with ts-jest.

My repo (and the create-account branch I'm currently on) can be found [here](https://github.com/Atticus29/video-annotator/tree/create-account). You can reproduce the error locally by cloning the repository, checking out the create-account branch, running `npm install`, and then running `npm test`. You may also need to create a './key.ts' file a populate it with:

```
export const secrets = {
  apiKey: "TODO",
  authDomain: "TODO",
  projectId: "TODO",
  storageBucket: "TODO",
  messagingSenderId: "TODO",
  appId: "TODO",
  measurementId: "TODO",
};
```

On the other hand, authentication is really the first main feature of the project, so I think that it could be relatively straightforward to follow the logic in the repo. without downloading locally.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't work much with NexTJS so please pardon me if I'm missing something.

I could get the tests running thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926763/5078746) just by adding:

```
module.exports = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)()),
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!(firebase|@firebase)/)',
  ]
});
```

And then the full `jest.config.js` file was like:

```
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",
    "^@/pages/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/pages/$1",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)()),
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!(firebase|@firebase)/)',
  ]
})
```

And I got that the tests are all green :)

```
Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       13 passed, 13 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.104 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Weirdly the examples from [their documentations](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-babel) show that we could add the same pattern in your `customJestConfig` object.

---

Side note: Please invalidate the secrets of your firebase app and make sure to delete them from your repository.